# Why is Entity Framework generating the following nested SQL for Azure Mobile Services Table Controllers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, odata, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to get to the bottom of an entity Framework issue when using it with a `TableController`

I've created the following setup.

1. The basic TodoItem example provided with a new Mobile Web API which leverages EntityFramework, TableController & the default EntityDomainManager

   ```
   public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
   {
       protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
       {
           base.Initialize(controllerContext);
           context = new MobileServiceContext();
           context.Database.Log += LogToDebug;
           DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request);
       }

       public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
       {
           var q = Query();
           return q;
       }
   ```
2. A vanilla Web API 2 controller.

   ```
   public class TodoItemsWebController : ApiController
   {

       private MobileServiceContext db = new MobileServiceContext();
       public TodoItemsWebController()
       {
           db.Database.Log += LogToDebug;
       }

       public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetTodoItems()
       {
           return db.TodoItems;
       }
   ```

I've gone through the `tablecontroller` code with a fine tooth comb, digging into the `Query` method, which is just proxying the call via the `DomainManager` to add in the `Where(_ => !_.IsDeleted)` modification to the `IQueryable`

Yet the two queries produce VERY different SQL.

For the regular Web API Controller, you get the following SQL.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
    [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
    [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
    [Extent1].[Complete] AS [Complete]
    FROM [dbo].[TodoItems] AS [Extent1]
```

But for the TableController, you get the following chunk of SQL which has a **Magic** Guid in the middle of it, and results in a Nested SQL statement. The performance of this goes to complete garbage when you start dealing with any of the ODATAv3 queries like $top, $skip, $filter and $expand.

```
SELECT TOP (51) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[Complete] AS [Complete], 
    [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[Text] AS [Text], 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], 
    [Project1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
    [Project1].[C6] AS [C6], 
    [Project1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
    [Project1].[C7] AS [C7], 
    [Project1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    [Project1].[C8] AS [C8], 
    [Project1].[Version] AS [Version], 
    [Project1].[C9] AS [C9], 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
        [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
        [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
        [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
        [Extent1].[Complete] AS [Complete], 
        1 AS [C1], 
        N'804f84c6-7576-488a-af10-d7a6402da3bb' AS [C2], 
        N'Complete' AS [C3], 
        N'Text' AS [C4], 
        N'Deleted' AS [C5], 
        N'UpdatedAt' AS [C6], 
        N'CreatedAt' AS [C7], 
        N'Version' AS [C8], 
        N'Id' AS [C9]
        FROM [dbo].[TodoItems] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC
```

You can see the results of both queries here. https://pastebin.com/tSACq6eg

So my questions are:

- Why is the `TableController`  generating the SQL in this way?
- What is the **magic** guid in the middle of the query? (it will stay the same until I stop and restart the app so I don't know if it's session, client or DB context specific)
- Where exactly in the pipeline is the TableController making these Modifications to the `IQueryable`? I assume it's done through some middleware step or an on executed attribute later in the request after the `Query()` method is called, but I cannot for the life of me find it.

Comment: I guess this is related with the mobile server SDK to implement Odata queries. I found if we use  var items= Query().ToList(), the sql query is right as the web api's. But we couldn't use the  Odata queries.

Comment: that's not really an option though because the client consumer will rely on using Odata $vars. e.g. on initial load it will use `$top` & `$skip` to apge through the APIs calls to perform the initial DB Sync.

Comment: This is because EntityDomainManager downloads and keeps values of fields along with each row for concurrency checks. And Guid is kind of ETAG from the source https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity/EntityDomainManager.cs

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your description, I did some research and found that Azure Mobile Server SDK uses the following code line under [TableControllerConfigProvider.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables/Tables/TableControllerConfigProvider.cs) for adding additional query related filters for the same actions with the [QueryableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.queryableattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for enabling a controller action to support OData query parameters.

```
controllerSettings.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider), new TableFilterProvider());
```

**Note:** the additional filters would be executed after your action has been executed and return the `IQueryable`.

You could check [EnableQueryAttribute.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.Http.OData/OData/EnableQueryAttribute.cs) and found that `OnActionExecuted` would call the `ExecuteQuery` method and eventually call [ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odataqueryoptions.applyto(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(System.Linq.IQueryable,System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQuerySettings)) for applying OData query options ($filter, $orderby, $top, $skip, and $inlinecount, etc.) to the given `IQueryable`.

Per my understanding, the Nested SQL statement is generated by OData component. After invoked `ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo`, your IQueryable has been modified and the related sql statement has been modified too. I did some test in my regular Web API Controller as follows, you could refer to it:

**Request:**

```
Get http://localhost:58971/api/todoitem?$top=2&$select=Text,Id,Version
```

**Before applying OData query options:**

[image]

**After applied OData query options:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your one of the tables being synced between the backend and client because if that your are getting 2nd sql.

Read more here :
https://documentation.devexpress.com/wpf/17927/Common-Concepts/Scaffolding-Wizard/Tutorials/Building-Outlook-Inspired-and-Hybrid-UI-Applications/Lesson-3-Customize-Layout-of-the-Collection-Views